# How can I find the indices of any two of the numbers, whose sum is equal to the target sum in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I'm doing this test on testdome.com for practicing , and it's failing some test case. Can anyone help me pointing out the logic error in my code?

This is the question for my code:

"Write a function that, when passed a list and a target sum, returns, efficiently with respect to time used, two distinct zero-based indices of any two of the numbers, whose sum is equal to the target sum.

If there are no two numbers, the function should return `None`.

For example, `find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10)` should return a single tuple containing any of the following pairs of indices:

- 0 and 3 (or 3 and 0) because addition of 3 and 7 is 10.
- 1 and 5 (or 5 and 1) because addition of 1 and 9 is 10.
- 2 and 4 (or 4 and 2) because addition of 5 and 5 is 10.

```py
def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
    sss=list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))
    if (sss == None or len(sss) < 2): return None

    for item in sss:
        tesn=target_sum-item
        if tesn in sss: 
            if numbers.index(item)==numbers.index(tesn):
                continue
            else:
                return numbers.index(item),numbers.index(tesn)
    return None
print(find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10))
```

They have four test cases and my code can only pass first two test cases.

Example case:Wrong answer ( to return [0,2] because 3 of index 0 + 7 of index  3 is 10) 
Distinct numbers with and without solutions: Wrong answer 
Duplicate numbers with and without solutions: Wrong answer  
Performance test with a large list of numbers: Wrong answer

Comment: Is `find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10)` an example case, they are referring to in the first test case?

Comment: yes it is an example case, and first test case.

Comment: @krisz ok I removed it.

Comment: Then skip the continue part and just do `if tesn in sss: return ...`

Comment: As an aside: `sss=list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))` can be written as `sss=set(numbers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on the problem:

```
def find_two_sum(lst, n):
    indices = {}
    for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
        indices.setdefault(num, []).append(idx)
    for k, v in indices.items():
        i = v.pop()
        if n - k in indices and indices[n-k]:
            return i, indices[n-k].pop()

print( find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 6) )
print( find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10) )
print( find_two_sum([1, 2, 1, 8], 10) )
print( find_two_sum([5, 5], 10) )
print( find_two_sum([11], 10) )
```

Prints:

```
(1, 4)
(0, 3)
(1, 3)
(1, 0)
None
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add a check for the **two indexes** to be distinct.
For example here:

```
print(find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 6))
```

The function will give an answer of `(0, 0)` which wouldn't be correct, though these are the indexes of `3`, which gives a sum of `6` with itself .

Here, I've added the check for distinct indexes:

```py
def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
    sss = list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))
    if (sss == None or len(sss) < 2): return None
    tup=()
    for item in sss:
        item_index = numbers.index(item)
        tesn = target_sum - item

        if tesn in sss:
            tesn_index = numbers.index(tesn)
            if item_index!=tesn_index:
                return (item_index, tesn_index)
    return None
```

Comment: in their question ,they say>>  should return a single tuple containing any of the following pairs of indices: 0 and 3 (or 3 and 0) because addition of 3 and 7 is 10, 1 and 5 (or 5 and 1) because addition of 1 and 9 is 10, 2 and 4 (or 4 and 2) because addition of 5 and 5 is 10, I am also not sure about the test case that is  Duplicate numbers with and without solutions

Comment: @kaythiswetun. Sorry, I misread - the distinction is on the indexes, not numbers...

Comment: I have edited my answer, since the indexes still have to be distinct

Comment: I don't see such check in the original code, look for example in the code I added to my answer

Comment: within the loop I checked the index like this 
            if numbers.index(item)==numbers.index(tesn):
                continue
            else:
                return numbers.index(item),numbers.index(tesn)

Comment: when I add condition , it gave the output 1,2

Answer (score 0):

One flaw in the logic is that `sss` does not contain duplicates that may exist in the original list - you have lost information. You are assuming there are no duplicates in the original list: `list.index(n)` will return the index of the first item equal to `n` so you can end up with a result with duplicate indices

```
>>> a = [3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9]
>>> item = 5
>>> tesn = 5
>>> a.index(item),a.index(tesn)
(2, 2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has a flaw e.g. `find_two_sum([5, 2], 10)` gives `(0, 0)`.
This is because when you check `item in sss`, it's gonna evaluate to true when `item` is `5`, there is only a single `5` in the input list.

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to be 50% correct.

```
def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
    for n in numbers:
        for i in numbers[numbers.index(n)+1:]:
            if n+i==target_sum:
                return(numbers.index(n),numbers.index(i))
                break
    return None

print(find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10))
```